# How can I resolve my pagination error indication "it doesn't exist on type"?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I want to add pagination to the products component, so there's only a maximum of 4 rows with 4 columns and you have to press a next button to see the next products. The pagination I tried implement gives a  'does not exist on type' error. [image]

The code in the html file is:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-3"  *ngFor="let product of products | paginate: {productsPerPage: 5, currentPage:p}" >
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix" >
                <span class="pull-left">
                    <img 
                    src="{{ product.imagePath }}" 
                    alt="{{ product.name }}" >
                </span>
                <div class="productName">
                    <p>{{product.name}} </p> 
                </div>
            </a>s

            <div id="pagination">
                <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p=$event"></pagination-controls>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="p=$event"></pagination-controls>
```

Instead of using this why dont you try in component

```
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="pageChanged($event)"></pagination-controls>
```

And call your next api request like this

```
pageChanged(event: any): void {
 this.apiService.getData(url?page=event);
}
```

Comment: Then you must include totalItems also

*ngFor="let product of products | paginate: {productsPerPage: 5, currentPage:p, totalItems: totalCount}"

Comment: I'm getting a 'totalCount' does not exist on type 'ProductListComponent' error now

Comment: you need to define totalCount inside componet like total count of your hardcoded data.

totalCount: 100

Comment: Thanks, that error is fixed now. And what about the property 'p' that doesn't exist on type ProductListComponent?

Comment: Think you need to set p = 1 initially inside your component file.

Comment: Can you paste your code of how you are using loop ?

Comment: It's almost working, it's now only showing a maximum of 12 per page, and a pagination bar. The bar isn't working at this very moment and I'm getting this error:  "Property 'pageChanged' does not exist on type 'ProductListComponent'.'' This is the loop: <div class="col-3"  *ngFor="let product of products | paginate: {itemsPerPage: 12, currentPage:p, totalItems: totalCount}">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix" >

Comment: If you're using static content then you dont need to add (pageChange)="pageChanged($event)" Try removing this one.

Comment: replace this (pageChange)="pageChanged($event)" with  this one
(pageChange)="p = $event"